# Restore the old behavior for SearchResponse in Elasticsearch 8

Tags: kotlin, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Due to missing compatibility with the GeoBoundingBox query I am forced to use ad-hoc the new Elasticsearch 8 Java client. According to the documentation, when using the search, a document class must now be specified that will be used for deseralization.
In the old search, a simple map with Key (String) Value (Any) was returned at this point.

How can I restore this behavior? We are using search across multiple entities, so we can't apply a specific type such as "Product" to the search result. Besides JsonNode/ObjectNode I had tried to follow Jackson and use something like this:

```
val searchResponse = elasticsearchClient.search(searchRequest, object : TypeReference<Map<String, Any?>>(){}::class.java)
```

But with this I get the following error message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "name" (class com.test.test.elasticsearch.QueryService$geoBoundingBoxQuery$searchResponsey$1), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
```

What do I do to recover the behavior from the old Java client?

Comment: I just read the docs for the new client. It looks like the best you can do is to pass as class parameter a JSON compatible class (ie: ObjectNode). That's how much close you will get from the old behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following solution:

```
val searchResponse = elasticsearchClient.search(searchRequest, JsonNode::class.java)

val content = searchResponse.hits().hits().mapNotNull { hit ->
    jsonMapper.convertValue(hit.source(), object : TypeReference<Map<String, Any?>>() {})
        .filterValues { it != null }
        .mapValues { it.value as Any }
}
```

`JsonNode` comes from jackson-databind (you need it anyway if you want to use the new Elasticsearch client)

In the second step, the individual json nodes are collected and converted accordingly using TypeReference. So in the end I have a list of maps, which is the same as it was before.